# Solving trigonometric equation $\alpha = \arctan(o/q) - \arcsin(b/q)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following equation:

$$\alpha = \arctan\Big(\frac{a}{q}\Big) \ - \ \arcsin\Big(\frac{b}{q}\Big)$$

The values $\alpha$, $a$ and $b$ are known, the only missing value is $q$. So I need to solve the equation for $q$ but I have absolutely no idea how to do it or even where to start.

I also tried putting this equation into Wolfram Alpha, but even this didn't give a usable output.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't seem that it would lead to the correct solution

$$\sin(\alpha) = \sin\bigg(\arctan\Big(\frac{a}{q}\Big)\bigg) - \frac{b}{q}$$

EDIT:

I've tried your hint @Kavi and I came up with the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
\tan(\alpha) &= \tan \Bigg(\arctan\Big(\frac{a}{q} - \arcsin\Big(\frac{b}
{q}\Big)\Bigg)
\\
&= \frac{\tan\Big(\arctan\big(\frac{a}{q}\big) - \tan\big(\arcsin\big(\frac{b}{q}\big)\big)\Big)}{1+\tan\Big(\arctan\big(\frac{a}{q}\big)\Big) \ \tan\Big(\arcsin\big(\frac{b}{q}\big)\Big)}
\\
&= \frac{\frac{a}{q} - \frac{\frac{b}{q}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{q^2}}}}{1+\frac{a}{q} \frac{\frac{b}{q}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{q^2}}}}
\end{align*}
$$

Is this correct so far?

Comment: $\sin\alpha = \frac{o \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{q^2}}-b}{q \sqrt{\frac{o^2}{q^2}+1}}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how did you made this up and how could I proceed with it?

Comment: $\sin(\arctan(t))=\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$. Now, squaring will lead to a montreous polynomial in $q$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the monstreous polynomial will still contain roots of $q$. No?

Comment: @denklo. Yes, for sure ! One of the problems is that we shall need squaring which introduces extra roots.

Comment: @Codey Why do you choose $o$ as variable name?

Comment: Yes better to change it to,say,$a$

Comment: Yes, what you have done the the Edit is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\tan (A-B)=\frac {\tan\, A-\tan \, B} {1+\tan \,A \tan \, B}$. It is very easy to find $q$ once you apply this formula for $\tan \, \alpha$.

Comment: Do you see any way to avoid a quartic polynomial in $q$ ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.